# Get first character of each string with BASH_REMATCH

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'am trying to get the first character of each string using regex and BASH_REMATCH in shell script.

My input text file contain :

```
    config_text = STACK OVER FLOW
```

The strings **STACK** **OVER** **FLOW** must be uppercase like that.

My output should be something like this :

```
    SOF
```

My code for now is :

```
        var = config_text
        values=$(grep $var test_file.txt | tr -s ' '  '\n' | cut -c 1)
        if [[ $values =~ [=(.*)]]; then
           echo $values
        fi
```

As you can see I'am using **tr** and **cut** but I'am looking to replace them with only **BASH_REMATCH** because these two commands have been reported in many links as not functional on MacOs.

I tried something like this :

```
        var = config_text
        values=$(grep $var test_file.txt)
        if [[ $values =~ [=(.*)(\b[a-zA-Z])]]; then
           echo $values
        fi
```

VALUES as I explained should be :

```
    S O F
```

But it seems \b does not work on shell script.
Anyone have an idea how to get my desired output with **BASH_REMATCH** ONLY.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637904/bash-regex-multiple-matches) to extract the strings one at a time if you MUST use regex and BASH_REMATCH, but for all the effort that requires isn't it just easier to split the line into an array and iterate over everything after the `=`?

Comment: If you have `var='config_text = STACK OVER FLOW'` then you can make an array using `read -ra myarray <<< "$var"` and then you'll have all your words in array elements 2+ to iterate over and process however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic BASH_REMATCH solution handling any number of words and any separator.

```
local input="STACK OVER FLOW" pattern='([[:upper:]]+)([^[:upper:]]*)' result=""
while [[ $input =~ $pattern ]]; do
    result+="${BASH_REMATCH[1]::1}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"                 
    input="${input:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}"
done
echo "$result"
# Output: "S O F"
```

Comment: This helped much because it treats the case if there is more than 3 words. Thank you for that @Philippe

Answer (score 1):

First Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

---

With the assumption that the line starts with `config` and ends with `FLOW` e.g.

```
config_text = STACK OVER FLOW
```

---

Now the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

values="config_text = STACK OVER FLOW"
regexp="config_text = ([[:upper:]]{1})[^ ]+ ([[:upper:]]{1})[^ ]+ ([[:upper:]]{1}).+$"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" = "$values" && "$values" =~ $regexp ]] &&
  printf '%s %s %s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done < test_file.txt
```

---

If there is Only one line or the target string/pattern is at the first line of the `test_file.txt`, the `while` loop is not needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

values="config_text = STACK OVER FLOW"
regexp="config_text = ([[:upper:]]{1})[^ ]+ ([[:upper:]]{1})[^ ]+ ([[:upper:]]{1}).+$"

IFS= read -r line < test_file.txt
[[ "$line" = "$values" && "$values" =~ $regexp ]] &&
printf '%s %s %s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

---

- Make sure you have and running/using `Bashv4+` since MacOS, defaults to `Bashv3`
- See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 1):

Bash's regexes are kind of cumbersome if you don't know how many words there are in the input string. How's this instead?

```
config_text="STACK OVER FLOW"
sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\)[^[:space:]]*/\1/g' <<<"$config_text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option rather than bash regex would be to utilize bash parameter expansion substring `${parameter:offset:length}` to extract the desired characters:

```
$ read -ra arr <text.file ; printf "%s%s%s\n" "${arr[2]:0:1}" "${arr[3]:0:1}" "${arr[4]:0:1}"
SOF
```